# How can I insert a list under a Table's tr

Tags: html

I need a `table` and also insert under a table's `tr` row a two more rows with full length and the only way I see to try and accomplish is putting a `list` under it. I really couldn't find anything about this and I would even appreciate knowing about some alternative way to accomplish this.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <ul>
    <li>Other data</li>
    <li>Other data two</li>
  </ul>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot have any other element than `tr` in that place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need rows that span the entire table width, use the `colspan` attribute on the `td` element in that row:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Other data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Other data two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you need an unordered list (`ul`), put it in the `td`:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <ul>
        <li>Other data</li>
        <li>Other data two</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Important**: This is an obvious ***misuse*** of a `table` element, which is meant **solely** *to display tabular data*.